# How to get patchwork to set different widths of a faceted ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I can't get `patchwork` to set different widths of a faceted `ggplot()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

mtcars$grp <- LETTERS[1:8] %>% 
  rep(each = 4)

mtcars$let_grp <- 1:3 %>% 
  rep(c(12, 12, 8))

p1 <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(
    let_grp == 1
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(wt, mpg)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~grp, nrow = 1)

p2 <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(
    let_grp == 2
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(wt, mpg)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~grp, nrow = 1)

p3 <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(
    let_grp == 3
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(wt, mpg)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~grp, nrow = 1)
```

`plot_layout()` works to make the subplots different heights

```
p1 / p2 / p3 +
  plot_layout(
    heights = c(2, 2, .5)
    )
```

[image]

But if I want the third plot to be less wide, the same strategy fails:

```
p1 / p2 / p3 +
  plot_layout(
    widths = c(2, 2, .5)
    )
```

[image]

How can I make the third plot half as wide as the preceding plots in a patchwork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `widths=` argument sets the relative width per column. And as your patchwork has only one column all three plots will have the same width.

One option which allows for more flexibility to place the plots and/or to set the width or height would be to use the `design=` argument of `plot_layout` or `wrap_plots`.

In the code below I use the `design=` argument to specify a "two-column" grid-layout, where the first (=A) and second plot (=B) should span both columns or the full row whereas the third plot should only span one column, where the `#` serves as a placeholder filled with an empty plot.

In the code below I simplified a bit by putting the three plots in a `list` which allows to use `wrap_plot`. But the same approach works with `plot_layout`).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

mtcars$grp <- LETTERS[1:8] %>%
  rep(each = 4)

mtcars$let_grp <- 1:3 %>%
  rep(c(12, 12, 8))

p_list <- mtcars %>%
  split(.$let_grp) %>%
  lapply(\(x)
  ggplot(
    x,
    aes(wt, mpg)
  ) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~grp, nrow = 1))

design <- "
AA
BB
C#
"

p_list %>% 
  wrap_plots(ncol = 1, design = design)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant--very incisive. the `design` argument seems very powerful!